# copying from buffer to buffer with a for loop working for all cases except for 0, stumped

Tags: c, string, buffer

I am currently trying to write a small program that tests a smaller functionality of a udp socket program. This section of code opens a file, stores the contents of the file into a buffer and then writes every 1024 bytes of the buffer into a section of another buffer (which is going to be sent as packets in the udp application), I also store a sequence number at the beginning of each packet. The file_buffer gets correctly filled but the packet_buffer does not. (at packet_buffer[0], it is all null)

The problem is that this works for all cases except for the 0th place in the buffer. Here everything is null.

My code is below, I have been stumped for hours trying to debug this little error.

Any tips, tricks, solutions?

```
#include "sendto_.h"

#define MAXBUFSIZE 102400
#define WINDOWSIZE 6
#define THEWINDOW 100

int main (int argc, char * argv[])
{ 
    /** file pointer to point to file opened by client to be */
    FILE* fp;           /**sent to the server*/

    /** Identifiers for the start and the*/
    int window_start, window_end;       /** end of the window */            

    /** window for GBN sliding window */                                
    char window[THEWINDOW];

    /** buffer to hold the contents of the file to be sent to server */
    char *file_buffer;

    /*set of buffers to be used to send approprate window packets */
    char packet_buffer[100][1024];

    int sequence_id = 0;
    int i, j, size, read_len;

    if(!(fp = fopen(argv[1], "r")))
                fprintf(stderr, "Error opening '%s': %s\n", argv[1], strerror(errno));

    // obtain file size:
    fseek (fp , 0 , SEEK_END);
    size = ftell (fp);
    rewind (fp);

    file_buffer = (char *) malloc(size * sizeof(char));
    /** size */
    read_len = fread(file_buffer, 1, size, fp);
    if(read_len > MAXBUFSIZE){
        printf("file size is too large: %d\n Exiting safely\n", read_len);
        free(file_buffer);
        return 1;
    }


    //printf("file buffer: %s", file_buffer);

    //snprintf(size_buffer, 10, "%d", read_len);


    /******************
      sendto_() sends immediately.  
      it will report an error if the message fails to leave the computer
      however, with UDP, there is no error if the message is lost in the network once it leaves the computer.
     ******************/

     //bzero(buffer,sizeof(buffer));

    /*loop that is going to deal with the main functionality of this 
      program: sliding window, sending packets and receiving ACKS.*/
     int k = 0;
     int count = 0;
     int temp;

     /*setting up packets to be sent */
    for(i = 0; i < THEWINDOW;i++){
        temp = i;


        packet_buffer[i][0] = i;
        sequence_id = packet_buffer[i][0];
        printf("sequence # of packet = %d\n", sequence_id);
        for(j = 0; j < 1025; j++){
            packet_buffer[i][j+1] = file_buffer[(j)+k];
            count += 1;
            if(count == size){
                j = 1026;

                i = THEWINDOW;
            }


        }
        printf("count: %d\n", count);
        printf("Wrote section of file into array: %s\n", packet_buffer[temp]);      
        k += 1025;



    //read info into each set of the packet buffer
    }




    window_start = 0;
    window_end = 5;

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: `packet_buffer[i][j+1]` is being overrun by two bytes.

Comment: elaborate? This still doesn't address the problem that every other section of the array is correctly getting written except for packet_buffer[0];

Comment: So, the entire 1024 bytes (1025 really) of `packet_buffer[0]` is nul?

Comment: Try using `count` as your index into `file_buffer`.  Again, not addressing your main concern but it cuts through some noise.  See my answer.

Comment: yeah its 1025 null bytes in packet_buffer[0]

Answer (score 1):

I would think:

```
char packet_buffer[100][1024 + 1];
...
for(i = 0, count=0; i < THEWINDOW && count < size;i++){
    packet_buffer[i][0] = i;
    sequence_id = packet_buffer[i][0];
    printf("sequence # of packet = %d\n", sequence_id);
    for(j = 1; j < 1025 && count < size; ){
        packet_buffer[i][j++] = file_buffer[count++];
    }
    printf("count: %d\n", count);
    printf("Wrote section of file into array: %s\n", packet_buffer[i]);      
    //read info into each set of the packet buffer
}
```

might be worth a try.  I think you're loops are being overrun, not your main issue, but a confusing point for me nonetheless.

*EDIT* Everytime I look at it, I see stuff to be pulled out of loop.

Answer (score 0):

I see a few problems.

1. You need to declare packet_buffer as packet_buffer[100][1025].  1 byte for the ID and 1024 bytes for the buffer data.  Total = 1025.
2. Your for (j...) loop is looping from 0 to 1024.  It should go from 0 to 1023 so that you transfer a total of 1024 bytes in each iteration of the i loop.
3. You need to add 1024 to k at the end of the j loop, not 1025.  Similarly, you can set j=1024 to exit the j loop when count==size.
4. You want to use &packet_buffer[temp][1] in your printf since the first char is an index and not from the file buffer.

Comment: Jamie's solution (posted while I was writing my answer) implements all of these comments.

Comment: I implemented all of these changes and the problem is still apparent. Stumped XD

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, since we were storing 0 in the beginning of the first packet as a char it stored a '\00' character which made the functions we were using to write the file stop as soon as it starts. Thanks for the all the help.